# Adding Same FlashBag Code To Every Controller - Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I need to add a FlashBag code `$session->getFlashBag()->add('foo', $bar);` to every controller, along with the code required to get `$bar`. I am wondering if there is a better way then copying+pasting the code into every controller? Would there be some sort of master controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you to create a listener that will run before every controller that you indicate. Following this guide will show everything you need to set it up:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html

Answer (score 0):

http://symfony2.ylly.fr/symfony2-simulate-preexecute-postexecute-filters-actions-jordscream/

You should try implementing a service and registering it for `onCoreController`, then do `$event->getController()->preAction()` (or whatever function name you want...) , then you can implement those methods in the controllers that you need functionality in

something like

```
src/My/Bundle/RequestListener.php:

public function onCoreController(FilterControllerEvent $event) {
  $evntController = $event->getController();
  if (method_exists($evntController[0], 'beforeFilter')) {
    $evntController[0]->beforeFilter();
  }
}
```

Look here for more info

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/internals.html#the-event-dispatcher

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/internals.html

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html